# Issues with setting classpath in Ant Script

Tags: ant, build.xml

I have some issues in setting the classpath for the a project for which Im trying to create a jar using the Ant build script. For eg: Consider a project A in the workspace. This project has internal dependencies with other projects in the workspace. There are project B, C, D in my workspace, which are added to the build path of the Project A. I have the below compile script in the build.xml. When I try to execute the script, the compile does not seem to happen, due to issues with classpath. Please find the code below.

```
 <target name="compileBusla"  description="description">  
    <antcall target="clean"></antcall>  
    <echo message="Creating directory '${target}' if not present "></echo>  
    <mkdir dir="${target}"/>  
    <mkdir dir="${Classfiles}"/>  
    <javac srcdir="../A/src" destdir="${Classfiles}" />  
    <classpath>  
        <pathelement location="../B" path="src" />  
        <pathelement location="../C" path="src"/>  
        <pathelement location="../D" path="src" />  
    </classpath>  
</target>
```

When I try to execute the script, I get the error at this line '' saying that compilation fails. Require help in setting the classpath in the buildscript. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you please post the full error message in your question? And also   `I get the error at this line ''` is not very clear, can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A classpath contains directories and jars which contain compiled class files. You added the source folder of A, B and C. Add their classes folder, or the jar file generated for these projects.

Moreover, the path attribute of pathelement is not just a directory name. It's a path. You should just use

```
<pathelement location="../B/src" />
```

Comment: Thanks JB. I did something similar to get the issue resolved. I set the <pathelement location="../B/src" /> and placed the classpath inside the <javac> code. Which resolved the issue. Thanks a lot